# Calculate or Clear wont' work

Tags: c#, button, calculated-columns

I am working on a Windows Form. Every time I press Calculate or clear, nothing happens. The form loads but buttons won't work. Textboxes remain clear, with no values. Visual Studio doesn't recognize the code as a mistake. Any help?

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
    {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        int numberOfInvoices = 0;
        decimal totalOfInvoices = 0m;
        decimal invoiceAverage = 0m;

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal txtSubtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEnterSubtotal.Text);
        decimal discountPercent = .25m;
        if (txtSubtotal >= 500)
        {
            discountPercent = .2m;
        }
        else if (txtSubtotal >= 250 && txtSubtotal < 500)
        {
            discountPercent = .15m;
        }
        else if (txtSubtotal >= 100 && txtSubtotal < 250)
        {
            discountPercent = .1m;
        }
        else
        {
            discountPercent = .0m;
        }

        decimal discountAmount = Math.Round(txtSubtotal * discountPercent, 2);
        decimal invoiceTotal = txtSubtotal - discountAmount;

        this.txtSubtotal.Text = txtSubtotal.ToString("c");
        txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("p1");
        txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
        txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("c");

        numberOfInvoices++;
        totalOfInvoices += invoiceTotal;
        invoiceAverage = totalOfInvoices / numberOfInvoices;

        txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = numberOfInvoices.ToString();
        txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = totalOfInvoices.ToString("c");
        txtInvoiceAverage.Text = invoiceAverage.ToString("c");

        txtEnterSubtotal.Text = "";
        txtEnterSubtotal.Focus();
    }

    private void btnClearTotals_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        numberOfInvoices = 0;
        totalOfInvoices = 0m;
        invoiceAverage = 0m;

        txtNumberOfInvoices.Text = "";
        txtTotalOfInvoices.Text = "";
        txtInvoiceAverage.Text = "";

        txtEnterSubtotal.Focus();
    }
}
}
```

I really appreciate your help, please let me know how I could improve.

Comment: Form1_Load is empty inside the brackets, i guess you want it like this             private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numberOfInvoices = 0;
        decimal totalOfInvoices = 0m;
        decimal invoiceAverage = 0m;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your click handlers seem to work fine. I am guessing you don't have them connected to the button objects for some reason. Maybe you created them, saved the Form1.cs file, and then opened the Form in designer and hit undo or something like that.

You should be able to make them work again by opening the form in designer, double-clicking the button and move the code to the new method created by the designer.

Once connected, the Form1.Designer.cs should contain the following line:

```
this.btnCalculate.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnCalculate_Click);
```

and similar for the clear button.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have fixed the problem!